# TextBox textchanged event is not working/not firing in asp.net When browser JavaScript disable

Tags: c#, asp.net

[click here for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOr1k.png)
My web page should work if browser JavaScript Enable/disable.

If browser JavaScript disable then I have to do some kind of complex validation .

When browser JavaScript disable TextBox textchanged event is not working/not firing in asp.net

1) Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoJavaScript.WebForm1"

2)form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off"

3)asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"  EnableViewState="true"

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;

    }
```

When browser JavaScript enable TextBox textchanged event is working/ firing in asp.net

Your support/suggestions are highly appreciated and welcome.
Thank's
Pradan Prasant Kumar .

Comment: You have added a screenshot of a text file?! Why not post all the relative information to stackoverflow?

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoJavaScript.WebForm1" %>

 <form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">

  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"  EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Looking at your text file screenshot, it looks like your TextBox1_TextChanged event in your .aspx page? It should be in code behind or at least in a <script runat="server"></script> block.

Comment: Did....did you really post a link to a screen cap of your question typed out in Notepad? WTF.

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: When browser JavaScript disable TextBox textchanged event is not working/not firing in asp.net

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoJavaScript.WebForm1" %>

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"  EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Jiraya, you may add a sentence or two just to emphasis what you think is the fix. Thanks